# MySQL db structure decision: many to many using link-table or parent id?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relationship

i'm a little bit stuck with deciding what db structure is the best for performance for me..

i have two tables:

```
Catalogue          Items
ID | Descr        I_ID | Descr
```

in both tables all rows are UNIQUE

in relations terms a records from `Catalogue` can have several records from `Items`, but there are records that won't have any `Items`

`Items` can have several relations to `Catalogue`, but not necessarily every item will have relation to a `Catalogue`.

Fact1 - there are 7 times more records in `Items` than in `Catalogue`

Fact2 - so if there is a relationship between `Catalogue` and `Items` - it will be equaly from both tables

what's my best option to relate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a third table, called `catalogue_items`. In the table catalogue_items have to columns:

1. ID  --> Referencing Catalogue ID
2. I_ID --> Referencing item ID

Make a new record for each time the two are related in some way.

**I believe this is what you were asking for in your follow up question:**

```
"Select * from catalogue_items where Catalogue.ID = catalogue_items.ID"
```

Comment: surely using parent id in one of the table will involve only 1 JOIN operation, while having third table will cause 2 JOINs? i simplified my question here, i have more joins already to Catalogue table, but they aren't related to Items...

Comment: Give me an example of a query you may need to make here and I will help you to create the proper SQL statement. Using this method, you can easily get any data that you may need.

Comment: no, actually the above query don't work as we didn't join `Catalogue` table... i need to select all items from `Items` and where applicable display `Catalogue.Descr` - how it's going to look with link table?

Answer (score 2):

The simple way would be have a intersection table such as :

Item_Catalog

CatalogId | ItemId

Comment: simple, but how about search performance? and i'm a bit unsure how my query will look like to join them...

Comment: Well if you have indexes on the primary and foreign keys it would be very fast.